# My Javascript Code doesnt work outside of JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, three.js, jsfiddle

For some weird reason my code will load and work in JSFiddle, however it will not work when I try using it outside of JSFiddle.
Does anyone know a fix? Or what is happening? Link to the JSFiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/56yK9/12/

```
If you go onto the jsfiddle link click "run" after the page has loaded.
```

To see my html document code: http://pastebin.com/D9eeVysr

Comment: check console for errors

Comment: did you include Three.js on your page "outside of jsfiddle"? Show us your HTML...

Comment: Yes I did >.> As everything works on my html document... but the sprite doesnt load. As opposed to JSFiddle in which it does load. I cant seem to get all my code on the Question ._.;

Comment: are you importing `Three.js` properly outside of jsFiddle?
what error are you getting?

Comment: Yes three.js is imported properly. No errors are occuring outside of JSFiddle. It's just that the sprite that loads in JSFiddle is not loading outside of it, in my HTML Document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here this code might help you... http://jsfiddle.net/ebeit303/e5Q3N/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r61/three.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body >
    <script>
        var container;
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var group;

        container = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(container);
        $(document).ready(function() {
            try {
                init();

            }
            catch (e) {
                container.innerHTML = e.toString();
            }
        });
        function init() {
            // renderer
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
            renderer.setClearColorHex(0xADD8E6, 1);
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2100);
            camera.position.z = 1000;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            group = new THREE.Object3D();
            scene.add(group);

            var tUrl = "http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/7344/ra2l3kgscpvjflafg.jpg";
            var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(tUrl, {}, spriteMesh);

            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
            animate();
        }
        function spriteMesh(ashTexture) {
            // create sprites
            var ashMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({map: ashTexture});
            var Ash = new THREE.Sprite(ashMaterial);
            var imageWidth1 = ashMaterial.map.image.width;
            var imageHeight1 = ashMaterial.map.image.height;
            Ash.scale.set(3 * imageWidth1, 3 * imageHeight1, 1.0);
            Ash.position.set(2 * imageWidth1, 2 * imageHeight1, 1.0);
            group.add(Ash);
        }
        function onWindowResize() {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            update();
            render();
        }
        function update() {
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        }
        function render() {
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your html document imageWidth and imageHeight equal 0, because the rest of the other functions/code doesnt wait until the image loaded from the site, (check it in your developer tool -> network) thats the problem here, so the sprite is invisible..your code might need changes..

```
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(tUrl, {}, callback);
callback = function(texture){
........code ur stuff here...........
}
```

just go through the code in the link it will give you some idea on image/texture loading... https://stackoverflow.com/a/21277768/2089677

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are missing an on page load / ready handler.
This little example seems to at least display something:
http://pastebin.com/NmnTeX6Z
You can take a look at a much cleaner output of your jsfiddle creation here:
jsfiddle.net/56yK9/show/

Comment: There is no effect with the problem